# WSPBuilder: Create a deployment package

Tags: sharepoint, wspbuilder, sharepoint-deployment

I've a site which have custom Theme, Layout, WebParts (third-party - no source code), custom user controls (with source code), and the site backup (.dat) which we took from command prompt using stsadm -o backup.

Is there a way I can bundle all of them in a single package? Should I use WSPBuilder for that? If not, then please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've guessed it right. You SHOULD use WSPBuilder to make this process EASY. Add all your resources in the appropriate folders to the 12 hive folders and build the WSP file. Though, i'm not sure why you're trying to bundle the site backups inside the WSP.

Comment: any idea how to bundle theme and style in WSPBuilder so it won't require to modify sptheme.xml manually.

Comment: there is another issue which i discussing there is there are some controls which required ajax extension. Currently, am installing the control on the pre-production machine and modify the web.config file manually. however Wictor suggests that i should use SPWebConfigModification. Is there a way that WSPBuilder do this too? If it can then HOW?

Comment: WSP builder can't automatically modify Web.Config to support ajax in your web application. Instead you should create your own feature to that modifies web.config when activated. Codeplex have it hosted and you can check it out here - http://www.codeplex.com/features. I've no idea about themes as i've not done much theming with SP. And yes, you have to use SPWebConfigModification to add ajax-requiring-entries into the web.config.